# Install Linode CLI on Windows

Tags: kubernetes, linode

The installation of the linode-cli should be straight forward on any windows system:
https://www.linode.com/docs/products/tools/cli/guides/install/#install-the-linode-cli

PIP3 and Python are installed and `pip3 install linode-cli --upgrade` worked just fine.
The package can be seen under `C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\linodecli`

Problem: The cli can not be called:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ linode-cli --help
bash: linode-cli: command not found
```

I've also tried to update the PATH variable but none of it works.